# Generate values inside an array declaration

Tags: python, arrays

For example something like this:

```
poo = [1,2,3,(value for value in range(3))]
print(poo)

>>> [1, 2, 3, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f7834fb1250>]
```

But instead of returning a generator for the fourth position, returning the following output:

```
poo = [1,2,3,(value for value in range(3))]
print(poo)

>>> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Most answers in the above-linked question will work for this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `*` like below:

```
poo = [1,2,3,*(range(3))]
print(poo)
# [1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2]
```

in python `*` for args and `**` for kwargs. see example([Keyword-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)):

```
def fun(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)
obj = {'b':10, 'c':'me'}
fun(100,**obj)
# 100 10 me


def fun(a, b):
    print(a, b)
l = [1,2]
fun(*l)
# 1 2
```

Comment: I don't think that we need `*(value for value in range(3))` ,  Just `[1,2,3,*range(3)]` works.